# Searchbox dosen't work when the input is erased react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm practing react redux and I'm making a simple CRUD.
I create a searchbox input, and works fine, but when I erased the input, the table with the data dosen 't update.
I alrready try save the result into the "search" in the initialState, but still dosen't work.
what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

I upload my code here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-wood-5ni19?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to:

```
case "SEARCH_DATA": {
  const { event } = action.payload;
  let res = [];
  if (event)  {
   res = state.data.filter( el => el.name.toLowerCase().includes(event));
  }
  return {
    ...state,
    data : res, // here is pass the result of the filter fn
    loading: true
  };
}
```